# Permissions and passwords error after Fresh install

Tags: system-installation, permissions, kubuntu, password

I have Ubuntu MATE 20.04, but I decided to give a chance to Kubuntu 20.04, so I made a fresh install but keeping the same /home partition of the first installation.

Now, every time I made a new login in Kubuntu it gives me some errors:

- It always asks to put the password in kwallet
- It forgets the browser passwords or logins
- It doesn't allow me to change files in desktop forlder ([image to error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97jdM.png))

So, I think that is some kind of permissions problems.

The fresh install was made with the same username and password than the last installation. [In this next image you can see the permissions of my user folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laApk.png)

Comment: Thanks, I edit the post and add a image of the error on the desktop. I think that is not a browser issue because in Mate works and both use the same /home configuration

Comment: So, what should I do? I have all my files in the home folder. Perhaps, deleting the config files?

Comment: One way to rule out if your problems stem from configs under the /home folder is to create a new user and see if the new user has the same problems.  If the new user is bug-free, you can migrate to the new user and remove the old one.  Don't forget to add the new user to sudoers.

Comment: The new user works well. Mi problem now is moving the files from de old user and that de username that I always use remains in the old user but it works!

Comment: There is a roundabout way to get your old username back but it involves some shuffling.  You can create a new user with the old username after you `userdel -r` (remove the user and home directory)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permissions issue, possibly caused by lack of ownership of your home directory. If your username is John, you would want to issue the following command to restore ownership of your Home directory, and everything in it to you.

`sudo chown -R john:john /home/john`

In the command above, replace "john" with the name of your user folder, all lowercase.

If your home directory and everything in it belongs to you, then you can try fixing permissions, with the following command.

`sudo chmod -R a+rwX,o-w /home/john`

That command should set all of the directory permissions to 755, and file permissions to 644 for user John. Files already marked as executable should remain as such.

Comment: Thanks! I tried several times, and spite that the command works, the errors that I had remain.

Comment: I added to my answer for you. Hopefully that can help you out.

Comment: Thanks! I try it but I'm still having the same trouble. Also I made a new installation. During one day it seems to fix, but today I have the same issues. I try your suggestion in the new installation but it also doesn't work. :(

Perhaps the issue is whit kwallet...

Comment: Curious... What happens, when you reinstall Mate 20.04 just as you had originally? Does this problem go away? If so, there could be something specific to Mate causing compatibility problems. You can also test by installing Kubuntu with a completely fresh home directory. This is usually what I do, if I change distros.